# C++ - Using a stack to determine if a C style string is a palindrome

Tags: c++, stack

I'm working on an assignment for class. We were provided with [these](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cop3330/hw/hw8files/stack.h) [three](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cop3330/hw/hw8files/list.h) [classes](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cop3330/hw/hw8files/listnode.h). (Linked here, the editor was flipping out when I tried to do them on separate lines).

We're supposed to take in a string and then use these classes to test if it's a palindrome. We can't modify said classes.

And here's my `int main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
   char testString[100];
   Stack<char> charStack;

   cout << "Please enter a string:\n> ";
   cin.getline(testString, 100);

   char caps;
   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(testString); i++) {
      if (isalpha(testString[i])) {
         caps = toupper(testString[i]);
         charStack.push(caps);
      }
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < strlen(testString); j++) {
      if (isalpha(testString[j])) {
         caps = toupper(testString[j]);
         if (charStack.firstPtr->getData() == caps) { // This part is the issue. firstPtr is private in list.h, and I can't figure out another way to compare the char array to the data in the stack
            charStack.pop(caps);
         }
      }
   }

   if (charStack.isStackEmpty()) {
      cout << endl << endl << "\"" << testString << "\"  IS a palindrome." << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << endl << endl << "\"" << testString << "\"  is NOT a palindrome." << endl;
   }
}
```

As you can see, I can't quite figure out how to compare the popped data to the data in the char array. The Stack class only returns a boolean, and the pointer to the ListNode object in class List is private, so I can't use the "getData" function of that class! Anyone have any tips that could help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: palindromes's are easy. Why use a class for them?

Comment: That's the assignment. Our professor is aware that it's much easier to do it other ways.

Comment: Are you kidding, having three links in 'these three classes' !???

Comment: Pop, compare, push back if not equal?

Comment: First pop it, thus yyou get the data, then compare.

Comment: @DieterLücking: The editor thought I had code in my post when I tried to separate them by line. Sorry.

Comment: @indiv: Wait, how do I compare after popping? Edit: Actually, just figured it out! Didn't notice that "value" was passed in by reference. So I can just pass in a blank test char, then compare that to the c-string! Thanks!

Comment: Please tell your professor that `List` is missing a copy constructor, [which is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/592323).

Comment: I don't understand why your stack `pop` method even takes an argument. Stacks pop elements off the top of the stack, which is why it's called a stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look  at function `Stack::pop(STACKTYPE &data)`

It takes a non-const reference argument in which it stores the element being removed (this actually happens in the implementation of `List::removeFromFront(NODETYPE &value)` ).

That means that you can pass a `char` to the `pop()` function and afterwards it will contain the data you're looking for.